# How to tell if event comes from user input in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, event-handling

I have a small form with some check boxes on it, and there's a message handler for each of the check boxes for the `CheckChanged` event. Since some of the check boxes are dependent on others, if one check box's checked state changes, it changes the checked state of any dependent check boxes. I've found that this causes the events to be raised on the other check boxes, but my issue is that each of the events has one function call that should only be called if the event came from the user actually clicking on the check box. I'd like to know how to tell (presumably from either sender or the `EventArgs`) if the `CheckChanged` event was caused by a mouse click or not.

Cliffs:

- Multiple check boxes receiving `CheckChanged` event
- Need to determine if event was raised by a mouse click or not

Comment: What about when they use the tab and space keys to navigate and select? I'd sort your logic out before venturing on breaking input methods.

Comment: I'd probably disconnect the event handlers for the change, then reconnect them.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of why you would want to know if it was the mouse that they chose to use?  It might help us.  In almost all cases I can think of, it wouldn't make any difference...

Comment: @Penfold This is one question where such detail is actually quite clear - because, side-effecting logic.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I read too much into the wording of the title of the question!  The title made it sound the like mouse vs keyboard input was the issue!  I see now...

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. @Grant, the same rules would apply to keyboard presses (I'd like the event to be fired), so the question could be reworded to say "How to tell if an event was caused by user input, and not as a side-effect of the program"

Comment: @Sean: I have edited your question to include tag of winforms. Please add these for any questions you ask, as it makes it clear and helps avoid guesswork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a flag to indicate whether or not to ignore events. Its probably easier than unsubscribing from the event handlers. Its not very sophisticated but it should do the job.

I put together a quick example:

```
   bool ignoreEvents = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ignoreEvents = true;
            checkBox2.Checked = checkBox1.Checked ;
            checkBox3.Checked = checkBox1.Checked;
            ignoreEvents = false;
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ignoreEvents) return;
            MessageBox.Show("Changed in 2");
        }

        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ignoreEvents) return;
            MessageBox.Show("Changed in 3");
        }
```

Comment: This did the trick, and it was quite simple to implement, thanks! EDIT: I am somewhat disappointed though that there wasn't a reply that could tease out the information from the arguments to the event handlers

Answer (score 0):

For more code stability you can also use the class TriggerLock instead of the ignoreEvents flag.

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (new TriggerLock())
        {
            checkBox2.Checked = checkBox1.Checked;
            checkBox3.Checked = checkBox1.Checked;
        }
    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TriggerLock.IsOpened)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Changed in 2");
        }
    }

    private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TriggerLock.IsOpened)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Changed in 3");
        }
    }
```

The class TriggerLock, it works like a semaphore:

```
public class TriggerLock
    : IDisposable
{
    private static int _nUsing = 0;
    private bool _bDisposed;

    public TriggerLock()
    {
        _bDisposed = false;
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _nUsing);
    }
    ~TriggerLock()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public static bool IsOpened 
    {
        get { return _nUsing == 0; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    private void Dispose(bool bDisposing)
    {
        if (bDisposing && !_bDisposed)
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref _nUsing);
            _bDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, but how does your class differentiate between events raised by direct user interactions (e.g. a user clicking a checkbox) and events raise by side-effect logic (e.g. the user clicks a checkbox, which causes other checkboxes to change state)?

Comment: The class does not implicitly differentiate between user interactions and side-effects. It is only an improved (exception proof) version of the idea from Alex.

Comment: I think the static `_nUsing` variable is a really bad idea. What if this class is used in two unrelated parts of the same project? This would cause end of confusion. It would be better to use an instance field and make the user keep and object of this class in a field.

Comment: This pattern works well in short code sections in a single thread. This is the most common case in a GUI. The class allows  nested locking and is exception safe. If you have to lock events in more than one dialog simultaneously or if you use multithreading for your GUI, you should change the pattern. I use the pattern already in VB6 ;)